# How do I create a related field in Products2 to Documents.Id?

Tags: custom-field, database, npsp

I am trying to pull in Document images to display on product listings (Product2 object) and wanted to just create a related lookup field to the Document Id. The image is displayed by a formula/text IMAGE() function on the Product page layout. I have it working if I copy/paste the Document Id into a text field that the formula references yet I would rather do it via a lookup field. Can this be done?

The end-goal is to be able to present products to clients, including an image (maybe in a shopping cart app or External site).

If it can't be done what's a better way (also being able to precisely control the image size, i.e. without pasting to a WYSIWYG text box)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't create a lookup to a Document. There's alternatives, depending on what effort you want to put in to this. For example, one project I did a number of years ago, we wrote a Visualforce page where the user would upload the image or select from one of the already-existing images. In the backend, this would set a Image_Id__c field (plain text), with a formula using IMAGE to display it on the detail page, list views, and reports.

Comment: There are many people with hands on our NPSP org and I was looking for a trick to avoid a VF page. I'd need an APEX controller, too, right? To upload an image with this method, are you able to store the image data as a document or in an object/field of my choosing?

Comment: @MikeStan. You could store the image as a Document, Attachment, File, or something else. Lots of options. Yes, you'll need some Apex Code. Unfortunately, there's not a great built-in solution for this. You might also take a look around the AppExchange? Maybe something's already out there you could use?